Proving the Uniqueness of the Method for Reducing Rational Tangle-Numbers to Zero from Conway's Rational Tangle
I am a high school student working with Conway's rational tangles and specifically with reducing tangle-numbers to zero using T and R operations. (I decided to not use the continued fraction form in the question, as I am not quite familiar with it.)
For those who aren't familiar with the concept: You can apply $T(x)=x+1$ or $R(x)=-{1 \over x}$
After playing around with some numbers, I came up with this algorithm:

When current tangle number is greater than $0$, apply R operation.
When it is not greater than $0$, apply T operation.

For example, lets say we have initial status of ${-7 \over 2}$.
Then we can turn it to $0$ using $T^{4}RT^{2}$ like this:
${-7 \over 2} \xrightarrow{T} {-5 \over 2} \xrightarrow{T} {-3 \over 2} \xrightarrow{T} {-1 \over 2} \xrightarrow{T} {1 \over 2} \xrightarrow{R} -2 \xrightarrow{T} -1 \xrightarrow{T} 0$
However, because of something like $R(R(x))=x$, there can be other solutions like $R^{2}T^{4}RT^{2}$, $T^{2}R^{2}T^{2}RT^{2}$, $T^{4}R^{5}T^{2}$...
But those variations at some point reaches a tangle-number more than 2 times.
My question is, is my algorithm the only solution where each tangle-number in the process is unique?
If so, it can be used as a proof that my algorithm is the solution with least number of operations. (Which is what I actually want to know)
After some trials and errors, I'm pretty certain with my conjecture but I have no idea about how I can prove it. I am looking for a formal mathematical proof or any known theorems that can confirm this uniqueness.

I don't have a proof supporting your conjecture, but I do have a counterexample.
If you define your starting value as $x = \frac{a}{b}$, and follow different algorithms based off the modulus of $a$ relative to $b$, you can construct a more efficient algorithm. Follow your algorithm whenever $a$ is not congruent to 1 modulo $b$. But whenever $a$ is congruent to 1, perform $-(R)$ whenever there is some $n$ such that   $a - bn = ±1$ i.e. the numerator equals one. This "flips" the tangle number at the opportune moment -- when flipping it reduces it to a negative integer, which $T$ can be performed on to solve. Doing some research as how to prove what you are asking, it appears that proving an algorithm's optimality is very challenging. The best way I have seen is by counterexample, which is what is done here.

Can you explain more about your counterexample? I quite didn’t understand it… are you saying that when there is number like -4/5 (where -4 is congruent to 1 modulo 5), you should apply R and make it 5/4? And what do you exactly mean by a-bn=+-1? Is n restricted to N or Z?

I actually came up with a simpler idea over the week: Basically, it is essential to make denominators smaller, and eventually make them 1 - then apply some Ts to make it 0. Let’s say we have starting value as a/b where a is negative integer. We can apply some Ts to make it r/b where r is congruent to a modulo b, and 0<r<b. Applying R here will make the number -b/r, which will make the denominator smaller as our intentions.
